# php array contains not working in multi language

Tags: php, arrays, utf-8, contains

```
$string = 'operating-system';
$array = array('operating-system');
$i = contains($array, $string);
echo ($i) ? "found ($i)" : "not found";
```

This above code prints **found(1)**

```
$string = '운영체제';
$array = array('운영체제');
$i = contains($array, $string);
echo ($i) ? "found ($i)" : "not found";
```

But this code prints **not found**. Why?

I have updated charset=utf-8

```
function contains($needles, $haystack) {
        return count(array_intersect($needles, explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $haystack))));
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code for `contains`

Comment: @Rizier123 : updated

Comment: FYI: As from your parameter names you normally search a [needle](http://imgur.com/b8JXyKa) in a [haystack](http://imgur.com/9NjQnsN) and not the other way around :)

Comment: So as I read your code you use a space as word delimiter and want to search how many words from the string are in the array, *right*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a native function that supports multibyte characters. Instead of `preg_replace`, you can use [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php).

```
function contains($needles, $haystack) {
    return count(array_intersect($needles, explode(" ", mb_ereg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $haystack))));
}
```

You may also want to check out the [docs for all multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).